# Is it possible to get GPS satellite numbers via iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, gps

Is it possible to get GPS satellite numbers via iPhone SDK ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Public SDK doesn't expose that.

Comment: Is this still true? The app id1020967894 (in the app store, just do a web search) shows signal quality for (almost) each satellite.