# Is there a way to get detailled GPS satellites info on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get GPS satellite numbers via iPhone SDK ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919553/is-it-possible-to-get-gps-satellite-numbers-via-iphone-sdk)

I am looking for the equivalent of `LocationManager.getGpsStatus(...)` on Android ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getGpsStatus%28android.location.GpsStatus%29)). More precisely it would be interesting to get, for all tracked satellites: their PRN numbers, C/N0, azimuths and elevations.

I know the SDK does not have any such interface, but does anyone know of a possible way to access to these values, or any software project showing such information?

Comment: Just an innocent and curious developer: Why do you need that?

Comment: typically for apps like this one : http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/GPS/GPS-Status-74495.shtml

Comment: It is similar, but the accepted answer for this question does not satisfy me.

Comment: Asking the same question again doesn't change the facts that it's not available.

Comment: The fact that there is no public API offering access to the information does not mean there is no way to access the information. e.g. private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public available API that allows you to get this kind of detailed information about the GPS satellites.